# Android Senty Integration

Tags: android, sentry

I am using sentry.io sdk in my android app to capture event and crash. But 
I am not able to see any event log in my sentry dashboard.
I followed the documentation from [this url](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/android/)

and done the `Progaurd` setup as well.
Here is the below code for capturing event

```
Sentry.capture("My Log event")
```

Comment: Have you seen any info regarding "Wait for 24hrs for getting your data sync in sentry.io documentation" from my suggestion every analytics tools need 1 day to get data sync so wait for some time.

Comment: No I have not seen any info regading"Wait for 24hrs for getting your data sync in sentry.io documentation" 
And I have integrated Sentry 3 day back still no events got tracked

Comment: Where to keep the sentry.properties file in the android project
And How to know that sentry gradel plugin for proguard uploaded the mapping file successfully

Comment: @BalaramNayak: I have the same problem. you can see [MY QUESTION HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53277487/6444297). Did you find the answer?