# Problem in setting up Sentry.io . Nothing sent to Sentry Panel

Tags: android, sentry

I'm going to use Sentry for My Android project I’m working on.
My company is using a self hosted Sentry, version 9.0.0

I followed [Sentry.io Installation Guide](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/android/).

These permissions were added in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is my **app/build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.10'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
}

apply plugin: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'

sentry {
    autoProguardConfig true
    autoUpload true
}
```

This is my top level project **build.gradle** :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'io.sentry:sentry-android-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

This is MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
    String sentryDsn = "https://MyPublicKey:MySecretKey...";
    Sentry.init(sentryDsn, new AndroidSentryClientFactory(ctx));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Sentry.capture("This Is My First Log!");
    ...
}
```

but nothing sent to Sentry Panel. What's the problem?

Any Ideas?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59070456/4797289

Answer (score 5):

**THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER I NEED BUT IT'S NOT BAD TO SAY**

Finally I found a solution to send Logs to Sentry panel using this class: [Sentry.class](https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android/blob/master/sentry-android/src/main/java/com/joshdholtz/sentry/Sentry.java)

however it needed some changes to work, but now it works like a charm.
The only thing that worries me is that when I open an event in Sentry panel this warning will be displayed at the bottom of the page:

> This event was reported with an old version of the java SDK.

To initialize and capture logs using that [Sentry.class](https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android/blob/master/sentry-android/src/main/java/com/joshdholtz/sentry/Sentry.java) copy its codes to a new class which you created in your project and find the below piece of code:

```
header.append("Sentry ")
        .append(String.format("sentry_version=%s,", sentryVersion))
        .append(String.format("sentry_client=sentry-android/%s,", BuildConfig.SENTRY_ANDROID_VERSION))
        .append(String.format("sentry_key=%s,", publicKey))
        .append(String.format("sentry_secret=%s", secretKey));
```

and replace `BuildConfig.SENTRY_ANDROID_VERSION` with a string which contains sentry library version. for example I added this dependency in my *app/build.gradle*:

```
implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.10'
```

now I should replace `BuildConfig.SENTRY_ANDROID_VERSION` with `"1.7.10"`

and also replace the string in this line:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "sentry-android/" + BuildConfig.SENTRY_ANDROID_VERSION);
```

and delete this line in comments:

```
* @see com.joshdholtz.sentry.Sentry#addHttpBreadcrumb(String, String, int)
```

Now just you need to add initialize Sentry by adding this line of code to your MainActivity:

```
SentryLog.init(this, yourDSN);
```

SentryLog is the name of my new class that contains Sentry.class codes.

Pay attention: you have to add deprecated DSN which is longer.

now you can test it by adding this line:

```
SentryLog.captureMessage("This Message Captured by Alireza Noorali.");
```

But I'll be glad to get better solutions.